# Prove the equivalence of the solution existence of Stokes equation's variational problem to the original problem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have this exercise. We put $X = L^2(\Omega)^4 \times L^1_0(\Omega), M = H^1_0(\Omega)^2.$

$$a : X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; ((\sigma,p),(\tau,\alpha)) \rightarrow (\sigma \otimes \tau)$$

$$b : X \times M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}; ((\tau,\alpha),v) \longrightarrow (\tau \otimes \nabla v) - (\operatorname{div} v , \alpha)$$

Prouve that the existence of solution to the problem

$$
\begin{cases}
&\mbox{find } (\sigma , p) \in X , u \in M;\\
&a((\sigma,p),(\tau,\alpha)) + b((\tau,q),u)=0, \quad\forall (\tau,\alpha) \in X\\
& b((\sigma,p),v) = (f,v) , \quad\forall v \in M
\end{cases}
$$

implies the existence of solution to the Stokes problem

$$
\begin{cases}
& - \Delta w + \nabla \Pi = f\\
& \operatorname{div} w = 0\\
& w=0 \quad\mbox{on } \Gamma
\end{cases}
$$

and I have no idea how to prove this. Thank's for the help.

Comment: who can help me please

Comment: What is $\otimes$?

Comment: And probably you copied your variational formulation wrong, you might wanna check the letters.

Comment: hi: he is the product tensoriel.

Comment: Then in $\sigma \otimes \tau$, $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are both matrices function? It does not look like this in your definition of spaces. In your definition $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are both $L^2$-integrable vector fields.

Comment: ok, i have a mistake and i edit it. Sorry, sorry, sorry. 4 not 2.

Comment: Hi, I just checked Brezzi and Fortin's book about mixed finite element, the mixed formulation he gave does not like what you wrote though.

Comment: i don't understand, sorry. Have you the solution of this problem please?

Comment: I know the solution for the mixed formulation for Stokes problem, but the mixed formulation I am familiar with looks nothing like you wrote: see table 3 in this notes http://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold//papers/mixed.pdf  Also in your definitin of $B$, what is $\alpha$ what is $q$, that's why I suggest check if the letters are alright.

Comment: i will see the problem later. Can you help me in the problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407829/lax-milgram-exercice please

Comment: okay, $\alpha$ is $q.$ i  edit my message. Sorry for this mistake. can you help me please

Comment: What's your purpose for this exercice please