# Use Lax-Milgram theorem to prove the existence of weak solution for an elliptic equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ an open bounded and regular domain to $\mathbb{R^n}$ and let $\{\overline{\Omega_1},\overline{\Omega_2}\}$ a partition of $\Omega.$ 
$\bar{\Omega} = \bar{\Omega_1} \cup \bar{\Omega_2}.$ We put $\Gamma = \partial \Omega_1 \cap \partial \Omega_2$ the interface between $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ such that $\Gamma \subset  \Omega.$

We put $u_1 = u/\Omega_1$ (restriction $u$ to $\Omega_1$) and we condider the problem:

$$-k_i \Delta u_i = f , x \in \Omega_1 , i=1,2$$
$$u_1=0 , x \in \partial \Omega$$
$$u_1 = u_2 , x \in \Gamma$$
$$k_1 \nabla u_1 n = k_2 \nabla u_2 n , x \in \Gamma$$

$k(x)$ is an piecewise constant , with $k(x) = k_i > 0, i = 1,2$  and $f \in L^2(\Omega)$

My questions are, how:

1-prouve that this problem admit a unique solution in an adequat Hilbert space $V.$

2- Prouve that $\exists c > 0, ||u||_V \leq c$ and prouve that $u$ verfies the minimum of energy.

Comment: Hi, @jijiii, did you see my comment in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402922/prove-the-equivalence-of-the-solution-existence-of-stokes-equations-variational ?

Comment: For the second condition on $\Gamma$, what is $\eta$, do you mean $k_1\nabla u\cdot n = k_2\nabla u\cdot n$? where $n$ is the unit vector normal to the $\Gamma$.

Comment: yes, n is the unit vector normal to $\Gamma.$ ($n$ and not $\eta$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big picture is: If $u$ satisfies those two continuity conditions on $\Gamma$ together with the equation in each subdomain, then $u$ solves the weak problem for the following diffusion equation on the whole domain:
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
-\nabla \cdot (k\nabla u )&= f \quad\text{in } \Omega,
\\
u&=0 \quad\text{on } \partial \Omega.
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

---

Multiply both equations by a same $H^1_0(\Omega)$ test function $v$:
$$
-\int_{\Omega_1}k_1 \Delta u_1\,v -\int_{\Omega_2}k_2 \Delta u_2\,v= \int_{\Omega}f\,v.
$$
Integrating by parts using Green's identity on each domain:
$$
\int_{\Omega_1}k_1 \nabla u_1\cdot\nabla v - \int_{\partial \Omega_1}k_1 (\nabla u_1\cdot n_1)v  + \int_{\Omega_2}k_2 \nabla u_2\cdot\nabla v - \int_{\partial \Omega_2}k_2 (\nabla u_2\cdot n_2)v =  \int_{\Omega}f\,v,
$$
where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the unit vector normal to the boundaries of $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ respectively. Now we focus on the boundary part, for $\partial \Omega_1\cap \partial \Omega_2 = \Gamma$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{\partial \Omega_1}k_1 (\nabla u_1\cdot n_1)v + \int_{\partial \Omega_2}k_2 (\nabla u_2\cdot n_2)v 
\\
=& \int_{\partial \Omega_1\backslash\Gamma}k_1 (\nabla u_1\cdot n_1)v + \int_{\partial \Omega_2\backslash\Gamma}k_2 (\nabla u_2\cdot n_2)v + \int_{\Gamma} (k_1 \nabla u_1\cdot n_1 + k_2\nabla u_2\cdot n_2)v
\\
=& \int_{\partial \Omega}k (\nabla u\cdot n)v + \int_{\Gamma} (k_1 \nabla u_1\cdot n_1 + k_2\nabla u_2\cdot n_2)v.
\end{aligned}
$$ 
The first term vanishes because $v=0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Second term vanishes because $$k_1 \nabla u_1\cdot n - k_2\nabla u_2\cdot n = k_1 \nabla u_1\cdot n_1 + k_2\nabla u_2\cdot n_2 = 0,$$
by $n_1$ and $n_2$ share the same magnitude but point the opposite direction pointwisely. By the other interface condition $u_1 = u_2$ on $\Gamma$, we know $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, therefore
$$
\int_{\Omega} k\nabla u\cdot \nabla v = \int_{\Omega}f\,v,\quad \forall v\in H^1_0.\tag{1}
$$

To prove the existence of a solution in $V = H^1_0$, we need to fulfill the conditions of Lax-Milgram theorem:

- $\displaystyle \int_{\Omega} k\nabla u\cdot \nabla v \leq C\|u\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)} \|v\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}$, this is trivial by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
- Coercivity relies on Poincaré inequality for $v\in H^1_0$: $\|v\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq c\|\nabla v\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$, so we have 
  $$\int_{\Omega} k|\nabla v|^2 \geq \alpha (\|v\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \|\nabla v\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2)$$
  for some constant $\alpha>0$ (You need to work out this $\alpha$, it depends on $k_1$, $k_2$ and $c$ in Poincaré inequality).

The second question is then trivial, let $v=u$ in (1), using Cauchy-Schwarz and Poincaré inequality on the right hand side:
$$
\alpha \|u\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}^2\leq  \int_{\Omega} k|\nabla u|^2 =  \int_{\Omega}f\,u\leq \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq c\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \|u\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)},
$$ 
hence the Céa's lemma holds:
$$\|u\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)} \leq \frac{c}{\alpha}\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}.$$

And if $u$ solves (1), $u$ also minimize the energy functional:
$$
\mathcal{F}(u) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega} k|\nabla u|^2 - \int_{\Omega}f\,u.
$$

---

There are several typos in your question, please double check your notes:

1. It should be $u_1 = u|_{\Omega_1}$.
2. It should be $u= 0$ on $\partial \Omega$, not just $u_1$.
3. There should be a dot product between the gradient and the normal, $k_1 \nabla u_1\cdot n= k_2\nabla u_2\cdot n$ because they are vectors.
4. "prove", not "prouve".
5. Céa's lemma has some norm of $f$ on the right hand side, because $\|u\|_V$ depends on that, you can't find a single $c$ satisfying that property.

Comment: $u=u_1 + u_2$??and $k=k_1 + k_2?$ i have problem to prove the first condition of Lax - Milgram

Comment: @jijiii No, $u|_{\Omega_1} = u_1$ and $u|_{\Omega_2} = u_2$, $k|_{\Omega_1} = k_1$ and $k|_{\Omega_2} = k_2$.

Comment: so how we can found that $$|a(u,v)| \leq C ||\nabla u|| ||\nabla v||$$?

Comment: @jijiii The first condition of Lax-Milgram can be proved by Cauchy Schwarz like I said in the answer: $$\int_{\Omega} k\nabla u\cdot \nabla v\leq \max\{k\} \|\nabla u\|_{L^2} \|\nabla v\|_{L^2},$$ then $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2} \leq (\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 + \|u\|_{L^2}^2)^{1/2} = \|u\|_{H^1}$ is trivial, if you square both sides you will find that the left is a part of the right.

Comment: Thank you so much! Please, can you help me in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408421/finite-elements

Comment: @jijiii I have two suggestions for you if you wanna get more of your questions answered: 1. accept the answer you satisfy with. 2. make the title of the question more clear about what you are asking about, not too long preferably.

Comment: Sorry, i undrestand this answer very very well and i accept it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @jijiii Okay, I suggest you read this thread on how to accept answers: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer  :)

Comment: Just one question please. In formula (1), it's better to write $$\int_{\Omega} k_i \nabla u_i . \nabla v dx = \int_{\Omega} f v dx$$ or $$\int_{\Omega} k \nabla u . \nabla v dx = \int_{\Omega} f v dx$$ ?

Comment: @jijiii The latter of course, for $k_i$ and $u_i$ are only defined on the subdomain. The integration is on the whole domain,  the test function is taken on the whole domain, and the latter addresses the continuity condition on the interface $\Gamma$ also.

Comment: @jijiii The whole point of this problem is motivating you to understand that for a big domain with interface, you can glue two solutions together using the continuity conditions on $\Gamma$, to formulate a globally $H^1$ weak solution to the PDE I gave in the very start of my answer.